# System.Web.Cache, Session level or Application level

Tags: asp.net, caching

Random quick question.

The System.Web.Cache class, at what level is the information stored? On a per session level or whole application level?

Thanks

Comment: Because the other answer had the link. Not only was it correct but it pointed to the place I should of looked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK at the application level.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx

From the page:

> One instance of this class is created
>   per application domain, and it remains
>   valid as long as the application
>   domain remains active.

Answer (score 3):

An instance of the cache is per app domain